# How to create table name uppercase in unity catalog

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We are trying to create a unity catalog tables on top of azure ADLS location for delta format. if we create table, the normally structure of tables look like always lower case, so that its impacting while connect SAS reports tools. we would have to make it all the tables while create unity catalog needs to be UPPERCASE. kindly suggest.

```
create table testcatalogname.test.tabl_ename
using delta
location "/test/delta/tablename/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the syntax below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE spark_catalog.default.DEPARTMENT
(
  deptcode  INT,
  deptname  STRING,
  location  STRING
);
```

In the example above, I created a TABLE with the table name in **UPPERCASE**.

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Learn more about [Create tables in Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-tables).

Comment: is this unity catalog based tables ?

Comment: we are doing on top of ADLS delta path, which means we did not give any column name, instead of that, we just use location on top create table with name. is this same which is applicable for us ?

Comment: also, if possible, to do SQL warehouse editor in Deatricks ?